# is there a way to store list values inside a loop in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to detect object using `yolov3` and `OpenCV` with python 
I want to store the coordinate of the detected object in JSON format but I am just getting the last coordinate how can I store all of my value in my list

```
for i in range(len(boxes)):
    if i in indexes:
        x, y, w, h = boxes[i]

        label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])

        labelSize, baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1)
        y = max(y, labelSize[1])
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y - round(1.5 * labelSize[1])), (x + round(1.5 * labelSize[0]), y + baseLine),
                     (255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 255), 1)
        # print ("x1=",(left,right),"y:",top,bottom,label)
        cv2.putText(img, label, (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0, 0, 0), 1)

        book = {
            "frame_url": "frame",
            "frame_width": width,
            "frame_height": height,
            "objeler": [
                {

                    "tur": label,
                    "x0": x,
                    "y0": y,
                    "x1": x+w,
                    "y1": y+h
                }]

        }

        s = json.dumps(book, indent=2)
        with open("f.json", "w")as f:
            f.write(s)


        cv2.imshow("Image", img)


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And this is the output I am getting

```
{
  "frame_url": "frame",
  "frame_width": 768,
  "frame_height": 360,
  "objeler": [
    {
      "tur": "arac",
      "x0": 273,
      "y0": 256,
      "x1": 299,
      "y1": 269
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a list outside of the for loop. Then, in the loop, you append to that list. When the loop ends you convert the list to json.

A general example:

```
import json
# create an empty list
books = []

for x in range(10):
        # add to the list
        books.append({"key":x})

print(json.dumps(books))
```

Edit: question in comments.
You can use [glob](https://pymotw.com/2/glob/) to get all filenames like this:

```
import glob
# location of images
folder = ""
# print all filenames of .jpg in folder
for filename in glob.glob(folder + "*.jpg"):
        image = cv.imread(folder+filename)
        # Process image...
```

Comment: thank you very much that really helped me
I want also to ask another question if you don't mind 
I am using this line of code to call my image (img = cv2.imread("frame12160.jpg")_but I can just call one image how  can I call multiple images every time and thanks in advance